# prevent .htaccess affecting subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following hosting setup:

```
/hostingroot/
 -/maindomainfiles/
 -/_sites/
  --/site1/
  --/site2/
  --/site3/
  --/site4/
```

The main domain "owns" the hosting. I have multiple other domains purchased through the same company pointed to the folders with `/_sites/`.

If I create a rule in .htaccess within the `/hostingroot/` folder, eg, `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)/$ http://maindomain.co.uk/$2` it effects requests for http://domain2.com/2011/pagetitle, not just http://maindomain.com/2011/pagetitle as I expected.

I have tried using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/_sites/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

but that didn't work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the RedirectMatch and going with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([^/]+)/$ http://maindomain.co.uk/$2 [L,R=301]
```